# AEM xtype selection cannot display special characters

Tags: encoding, selection, aem, display

I am working on AEM 6.1
My problem is the selected options cannot display the characters when I select it.
But the dropdown list displays the correct characters.[image: selection dropdown list]

**here is the value when it is selected**
[image]

The return from the server is a JSON object with values 
`{"text":"&#x414;&#x440;&#x443
;&#x433;&#x43E;&#x435;","value":"?somequeryparametershere"}`

Do I need to configure something in the `dialog.xml`?
I checked the allowed attributes for the `xtype="selection"` which can help in the rendering the characters or encoding them to utf-8 but could not find any from this link https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection#CQ.form.Selection-options

Dialog definition

```
<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
    <pageCategory 
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
        fieldLabel="Page Category" 
        fieldDescription="A reload is required for changes to take effect. If changed: Press OK and then reload the page" defaultValue="Global select configured" 
        name="./pageCategory" 
        options="$PATH.categories.json" 
        type="select" 
        xtype="selection"/> 
</items>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: java and os versions?

Comment: Can you post there dialog definition?

Comment: Hi Alex, here is the dialog definition <br /> `<items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
       <pageCategory
         jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
         fieldLabel="Page Category"
         fieldDescription="A reload is required for changes to take effect. If changed: Press OK and then reload the page"
         defaultValue="Global select configured"
         name="./pageCategory"
         options="$PATH.categories.json"
         type="select"
         xtype="selection"/>
      </items>`

Comment: Hi awadheshv, java jdk1.8 and then OS Rad Hat 6.5 64 bit

Comment: @Racs, please, when answering somebody, preppend their names with '@' so they will be notified about your answer. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Alex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@racs
I just tried simulating this issue in my local. You will have to add this page directive in categories.json.jsp <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

[image: Dropdown]
[image: Selection]
[image: Categories json]

If you are using a templating language like sightly or handlebars, there will be changes in the syntax to include the page directive.